# java sending the frame to front of screen

Tags: java, jframe

Is there a way to send the java frame in front of every other opened program. I know you can use

```
 JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

but that just keeps it in front allways. I want it to only happen when a certain function is called. For instance, When I press a button on a frame, it will wait using Thread.sleep(10000) for ten seconds, but the I want it to just the frame to the front in case you clicked out of the window for a second. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Window#toFront`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29)

You may also want to take a look at

- [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)
- [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Be careful of using `Thread.sleep` in a GUI environment, if used incorrectly, this will cause you window to stop updating (painting)

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly fiddly.

The exact behavior might also depend on the operating system. But at least on Windows, a call to `frame.toFront()` will **not** necessarily bring the window to the front. Instead, it will cause the corresponding entry in the task bar to blink for a few seconds. I tried something like

```
f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
f.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

which basically works, but after the window was brought to the front, it is *not* "active", and none of my attempts to make it active worked (e.g. requesting the focus or so).

The only solution that I found now to (reliably) work (on Windows, at least) was

```
if (!f.isActive())
{
    f.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    f.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
}
```

But wonder wheter there is a more elegant solution.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FrameToTopTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Bring me to top after 3 seconds");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                triggerBringToFront(f, 3000);
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(button);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void triggerBringToFront(final JFrame f, final int delayMS)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(delayMS, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // This will only cause the task bar entry
                // for this frame to blink
                //f.toFront();

                // This will bring the window to the front,
                // but not make it the "active" one
                //f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                //f.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

                if (!f.isActive())
                {
                    f.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
                    f.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }


}
```